# naming subgraphs in graph

Tags: python-3.x, graph, igraph

I have data set where rows related to each other using multiple keys. This data set can be represented as a graph. I need to assign common keys using the main key from the node which first in each subgraph ordered by input order.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using igraph library.

```
g = igraph.Graph()
g.add_vertices("m1")
g.add_vertices("s1")
g.add_vertices("s2")
g.add_vertices("m2")
g.add_vertices("s3")
g.add_vertices("m3")
g.add_vertices("s4")
g.add_vertices("m4")
g.add_vertices("m5")
g.add_vertices("m6")
g.add_edges([("m1", "s1"),("m1", "s2"),("s2", "m2"),("m2", "s3"),("m3", "s4"),("s4", "m4"),("s4", "m5")])


gl = g.clusters()
print(gl)`
[0] m1, s1, s2, m2, s3
[1] m3, s4, m4, m5
[2] m6
```